Is it possible to prevent kubernetes HPA from removing a specific pod when scaling down?
In one of my deployments, one pod of the deployment has to do a certain task which is long running, which other pods don't have to do.
I have setup an HPA to scale up/down the pods of this deployment based on cpu usage. When the HPA detects it needs to scale down the number of pods, HAP would randomly pick a pod and terminate it. I want to prevent HPA from removing the pod that has the long running task in this situation.
Is there a way to achieve this?

The HPA just changes the Deployment's replicas: parameter.  The linked question has a couple of workarounds here.  Your Pods would need permission to access the Kubernetes API if they figure out they're doing long-running work.
